# How to upgrade a “minimal” install of 18.04 to Normal 18.04 Server

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-minimal

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 minimal from Hetzner, but my script wont run on minimal to much missing packages libraries. How can i upgrade to normal 18.04 server with full packages options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `ubuntu-server` metapackage

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-server
```